# Compare fields in multiple files

Tags: unix, awk

I have some files. Each file has contents like shown below. (parameters, each having a value). Each parameter is in a new line.

`x=1
y=23
z=30`

I want to print the file name and the parameter with its value, only if the parameter is not having the same value in all the files. (If there are three files and say x is 1 in two files and 2 in the other then x should be considered for output). Please suggest me a solution in shell script.

Comment: For three files, consider `diff3`, assuming the entries are in the same order in each of the files.  If the orders are truly randomized, then consider sorting the files before comparing.  If you must use `awk`, then you need to watch out for entries that are missing in the first file but present in the second or third files.  Such entries probably need to be printed — but the solutions I see would not spot this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following line will store a map from the parameter name to the parameter value and output any non-matching filename, key, and value. Note that it only outputs and the second and/or third line that causes a conflict, not the original value.

You will need to store the filename of the original if you want to also output the original that caused the conflict.

```
awk -F'=' '{if($1 in arr && arr[$1] != $2) print FILENAME, $1, $2; arr[$1] = $2}' File1  File2 File3
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different from merlin2011, but same basis:

```
awk -F'=' '{if(!x[$1]){x[$1]=$2;next} if(x[$1]!=$2){print FILENAME":" $0}}' file1 file2 file3
```

Mine assigns the value to the array if it is not assigned and then ignores the line using `next`.